# Why does the marquee not stop when I press the mouse button down?

Tags: html, css, mouse, marquee

This is my code

```
<marquee scrollamount="3" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()"> 
  This is the marquee
</marquee>
```

This piece of code doesn't seem to get validated either.

Comment: Isn't it case-sensitive? **onMouseOver** and **onMouseOut**? But neither of these will do anything *onClick*

Comment: On which browser(s) does that happen? Since you are using `onmouseover`, the marquee stops as soon as you move the mouse pointer over the element (with no need for pressing any button). Did you expect it to stop when you press the mouse button while the pointer is over some other element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work I think

```
<marquee  onmouseover="this.scrollAmount = 0" onmouseout="this.scrollAmount = 3"> This is the marquee</marquee>
```

But please note, the marquee tag should not really be used anymore as it is or will be deprecated soon, and should only work on old browsers.  It may still work for now, but probably wont work for much longer.  This type of text formatting should really be done in JS.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry about that delay but thank you @Sam Denton

Answer (score 1):

here is the code:

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.scrollAmount = 0" onmouseout="this.scrollAmount = 3"> 
    This is the marquee
</marquee>
```

i hope it did helps you